# Is necessary to call end after json in node.js?

Tags: node.js, express

In express and node a return a json and after i call end.

Is necessary to call

```
res.end()
```

after

```
res.json()
```

?

Comment: No. https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example from docs;
https://expressjs.com/en/api.html

You **do not** need.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

You don't have to call `res.end()` if you call `res.json()`. `res.json()` calls `res.end()` for you.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not necessary to call `res.end()` after you have called `res.json()` (or `res.send()` or `res.render()`).